# WPF GridViewRowPresenter in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

I'm just starting learning WPF and I'm trying to use a GridViewRowPresenter inside of an ItemsControl to essentially duplicate the functionality of a simple table in HTML. The ListView is not appropriate since it is interactive (which I don't want). I am binding to a generic List of objects of an unknown quantity.

I have a List of a custom object that has two string properties: FirstName and LastName. The following code works:

```
<ItemsControl Name="myItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

while this renders nothing:

```
<ItemsControl Name="myItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GridViewRowPresenter>
                <GridViewRowPresenter.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumnCollection>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"></GridViewColumn>
                    </GridViewColumnCollection>
                </GridViewRowPresenter.Columns>
            </GridViewRowPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here and I would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a non-interactive grid of items, you can use an `ItemsControl` with a `Grid` that uses shared size scope:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="FirstName"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="LastName"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

A more efficient approach would be to write your own `Panel` subclass that works similarly to `Grid` (you could probably subclass `Grid`) but automatically adds rows as necessary. Then use that `Panel` as the `ItemsPanel` for the `ItemsControl`.

Comment: I am facing a related issue, I wish you could help me, [please take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251183/wpf-two-dimentional-datagrid-listview "WPF Two-Dimentional-DataGrid/ListView")