# WPF Two-dimensional DataGrid/ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid, pivot-table, multidimensional-array

I have a table `Item` that consists of 3 columns:

```
ItemId int PK
RoomId int FK
UnitId int FK
Cost money
```

I want to have a DataGrid/ListView having dynamically-generated columns and rows representing the following pivot:

```
       Room1 Room2 Room3 Room4 
Unit1  $34   $72   $48   $98
Unit2  $64   $56   $67   $24
Unit3  $24   $34   $34   $34
```

I prefer a control or a helper to an existing one rather than a dirty function since I am gonna need this scenario a lot, but anything at all is warmly welcommed.

I want to have the `Room1` and the `Unit1` etc. as row and column headers, and the cells generated/set accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you'd need to convert your collection of `Item` objects into a suitable collection:

```
var dict = data.Select(i => i.UnitId).Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(u =>  u, u => data
        .Where(i => i.UnitId == u)
        .ToDictionary(d => d.RoomId, d => d));
var rooms = dict.Values.First().Keys;
DataContext = Tuple.Create(dict, rooms);
```

and then you need an `ItemsControl` with the correct `DataTemplate` configuration

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Item2}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="80,0,0,0" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   Width="80"
                   Margin="5">
                        <Run Text="Room" />
                        <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Item1}"
                AlternationCount="{Binding Count}"
                Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Foreground="Blue"
                     Width="80">
                        <Run Text="Unit" />
                        <Run Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}" />
          </TextBlock>
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Cost, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"
                           Margin="5"
                           Width="80" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

and then you get this:

[image]

Comment: great! awsome! Do you think of a way that I will be able to use DataGridColumnHeader and DataGridRowHeader for the headers?
I think I am looking for a custom control that inherits Selector or MultiSelector that should have a ColumnItemsSource, RowItemsSource and an event GeneratingCell that its EventArgs provides current cell Item + Unit, and a property I have to supply the generating cell's DataContext, then, it generates the cell against the CellDataTemplate property. but since I have no serious experience with developing custom controls it's very hard for me to start from scratch.

Comment: Especially when the cell data item is unknown and is supplied by user on demand. Meanwhile I am gonna use your solution, I hope you'll get some time to post a custom control. the whole comminity will owe you for it. such a control is very essential.