# Connecting width/height of cell in two different controls?

Tags: wpf, binding, performance, relativesource, elementname

I need to create two controls that contain the same amound of items (a dynamic amount), the first control represents the keys, the second represents the values.

I need it so that when the user resizes the upper column width it should affect the same column in the lower row (of the values).

Here is an example to what I desire:

```
<Window 
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
  x:Class="MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Window.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate">
      <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}" 
                  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" 
                  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Class MainWindow
  Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object,
                            ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    DataContext =
      New StringDictionary From
      {
        {"key1", "value1"},
        {"key2", "value2"},
        {"key3", "value3"},
        {"key4", "value4"}
      }
  End Sub
End Class
```

Result:

[image]

Again, I want to be able to create a DataGrid-like control that even supports cell borders and cell widths and heights should be connected to the other controls' width + allow resize.

I prefer it to be done xamly.
Note: it's a custom control, so I can declare appropriate properties if necessary. but remember the cells' heights and width has to be dynamic and individual to specific columns/rows.

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251183/wpf-two-dimensional-datagrid-listview) question, I created it in a slightly different way (having a third control for cells), but the question is still the same, I want the height width of the columns and cells to be dynamic, and give the user ability to resize them affecting each other.

**UPDATE**

[decyclone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331927/connecting-width-height-of-cell-in-two-different-controls/4334387#4334387) is something I would love to implement, but I tried the example he provided setting the `ItemsControl`s' `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` property to true, but it didn't work, here is the result (cropped):

[image]

Is it possible to apply a shared size scope between two different controls?

Comment: Do you have to use two seperate `ItemsControls`?? If you want to keep width and height of the cells the same, why not use a single `ItemsControl` with two row data `ItemTemplate` in it?

Comment: @decyclone, yes. I considered that, I do have to use separate `ItemControl`s, since my particular scenario is slightly different than the example above. I have dynamically auto-generated columns and rows (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251183/wpf-two-dimensional-datagrid-listview "WPF Two-dimensional DataGrid/ListView?"), and I want to keep the cells ItemsSource seperated, but still connected as long as it concerns cell size.

Comment: Have you considered using `Shared Size` using `SharedSizeGroup` and `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`?

Comment: I tried that actually but I didn't manage to work with it, my guess is that it's meant to serve only items generated in the same ItemsControl as the same `ItemTemplate` wrapper, I wish you'd tell me it can work between two controls!

Comment: I had the very similar problem. Finally I end up creating dynamic template and resolved the issue. It is quite difficult to explain in word. I'll create a sample and provide soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something and seems to work :

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:GroupNameGenerator x:Key="GroupNameGenerator1" />
        <local:GroupNameGenerator x:Key="GroupNameGenerator2" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl1">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GroupNameGenerator1}}" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Padding="5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl2">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GroupNameGenerator2}}" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Padding="5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Int32> list1 = new ObservableCollection<Int32>();
        ObservableCollection<String> list2 = new ObservableCollection<String>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                list1.Add(i + 1);
                list2.Add(new String('0', ((i + 1) / 3)));
            }

            ItemsControl1.ItemsSource = list1;
            ItemsControl2.ItemsSource = list2;
        }
    }

    public class GroupNameGenerator : IValueConverter
    {
        public Int32 Index { get; set; }

        public GroupNameGenerator()
        {
            Index = 0;
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return String.Format("Group{0}", ++Index);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And of course, don't forget to set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on Root panel that contains both ItemsControls.

Comment: Your example doesn't work as expected, see my updated answer.

Comment: Code updated. Provided complete and simplified code. It does work.

Comment: Dude, thanks for the effort! **The magic secret is** specifying `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` on the parent container...

Comment: That's what I tried to explain in my first comment in this post. :)