# Bind two-dimensional string-Array to list view in WPF

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, data-binding

I query some data from multiple databases and save them in a two-dimensional string array like this:

```
string[databaseID,fieldID]
```

... where fieldID = 0 represents the Name of the field.

The number of databases varies and can be between at least one and an undefined number.
The number of fields is determined.

I want to have one column for the field names and one column for each databaseID.
Each row should contain the data of a specific field of each database.
It should for example look something like this:

```
FieldName | Database1 | Database2 | Database3
----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
Name1     |     A     |     B     |     A
----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
Name2     |     1     |     2     |     3
```

How can I do this?

For creating the column headers, I already have this:

```
GridView gridView = new GridView();
gridView.AllowsColumnReorder = true;

GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("");
gvc1.Header = "Feldname";
gvc1.Width = 100;
gridView.Columns.Add(gvc1);
for (int i = 0; i < databases.Count; i++)
{
    GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
    gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Path=Row[" + (i + 1) + "]"); //Still not sure, wether this is okay
    gvc.Header = databases[i].DisplayName;
    gvc.Width = 100;
    gridView.Columns.Add(gvc);
}
lvBasic.View = gridView;
```

The XAML part I refer to is rather simple:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListView Name="lvBasic">
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**UPDATE:** I thought it wouldn't matter, so I left out an aspect of my problem. I need to compare the data of database1 with all other databases and therefore need this layout or some other layout which is suitable for that task.

Comment: Wouldnt it be much easier, to create a new object, containing the Array-Data and simply group them? That might increase the readability too

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: The thing you're looking for is a `PivotGrid`. Unfortunately this is not built in but there are many companies offering such possibilities in their frameworks (Telerik, Infragistics, DevExpress, etc). Needless to say, you wont get em for free :(

Comment: @lokusking So, is there an hack or a workaround to get what I want? It doesn't have to be pretty. :)

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4254842/4558029) if you have a similar Data-Structure

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach to explain my comment.

**XAML**

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding DataObjects}" x:Key="CollectionViewSource" >
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="DatabaseId"/>
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSource}}">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>

            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldId}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>           
    </Grid>
```

**DataObject**

```
 public class DataObject {

    public string DatabaseId { get; set; }

    public string FieldId {
      get; set;
    }

  }
```

**Usage**

```
 this.DataObjects = new List<DataObject>();
      this.DataObjects.Add(new DataObject {DatabaseId = "Db1", FieldId = "FieldName"});
      this.DataObjects.Add(new DataObject { DatabaseId = "Db1", FieldId = "FieldFirstName" });
      this.DataObjects.Add(new DataObject { DatabaseId = "Db2", FieldId = "FieldName" });
      this.DataObjects.Add(new DataObject { DatabaseId = "Db2", FieldId = "FieldDate" });

      this.DataObjects.Add(new DataObject { DatabaseId = "Db3", FieldId = "FieldName" });
      this.DataObjects.Add(new DataObject { DatabaseId = "Db3", FieldId = "FieldDate" });
      this.DataObjects.Add(new DataObject { DatabaseId = "Db3", FieldId = "FieldFirstName" });
      this.DataObjects.Add(new DataObject { DatabaseId = "Db3", FieldId = "FieldId" });
```

**Result**
[image: resultImage]

This is an 100% MVVM-Conform solution. You can just simply group and expand by your Database (or just reverse the logic if that fits your needs better).
Please note, that my `DataObject` has nothing in common with your actual datastructure. I made this in about 7 minutes and it should give you an alternate view.

Cheers

Comment: That's actually not bad. The problem is, that I left out an aspect in my explanation to simplify it. I want to compare some data of a specific database with all other databases. Therefore I'd like to have it in that column-style-view.  Database1 is kind of a master database I'd like to compare all data against.